# What are the parameters typically used by airlines to assess the fuel economy and efficiency for their flights?

Tags: airline-operations, fuel, efficiency, performance-calculation, fuel-consumption

Are there parameters that are typically being used by airlines to assess the fuel economy and efficiency done in their flights?

And how exactly those parameters are being used to do the assessments and formulating future flight strategies to make them more efficient?